# Syntax for selecting particular column value from memo field in progress database

Tags: java, sql, openedge, progress-db

I'm using progress database,I have a field doc_desc which is memo. In that I need to retrieve data starts with @. Can anyone help with the syntax in Java.
I wrote my code like this:

```
SELECT LEFT(Doc_Desc,LEN(Doc_Desc) - CHARINDEX('@', Doc_Desc, 1)) from PUB.GLDOCHDR where Doc_Desc like '%@%'
```

but this is giving me a syntax error

Comment: No idea what progress DB is, but how this has anything to do with Java? The query you wrote is SQL and seems almost correct for your case. "like '%@%'" selects all texts that CONTAIN @. Change it to "like '@%' to get only lines that start with @.

Comment: Might help to see the actual error.  Usually those things have clues as to what the interpreter thought was erroneous in the request.

Answer (score 1):

OpenEdge (Progress) does not support a "charindex()" function.  You are probably wanting to use INSTR() or SUBSTR() or SUBSTRING().

The documentation is here:  http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge113/oe113html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Data%20Management/SQL%20Reference/06dmsrfFnctn.138.083.html

Comment: i tried this but in progress its not identifying select left.its showing unable to understand after select.

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you trying to use?  The documentation link will show you what is actually supported in the current release (11.3).  If you're using something older that might matter too.  Also -- LEN should probably be LENGTH